# PHP import entries from .csv file - MySQL query issues

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import some entries from a .csv file into my actual database. I have done this a thousand times without any issues. Starting with yesterday, I can't import it anymore.

I am always getting this error:

```
Error Number: 1242

Subquery returns more than 1 row

UPDATE preturi_import I SET I.art_id = ( SELECT ART_ID FROM tof_articles WHERE I.art_nr = ART_ARTICLE_NR AND I.sup_id = ART_SUP_ID ) WHERE I.sup_id > 0

Filename: /home/pieseaut/public_html/controllers/backend.php

Line Number: 1647
```

Since the script was working just fine until yesterday and I haven't done any modifications to the script I really can't understand what the problem might be.

The exact mysql query is as follows:

```
 $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE preturi_import I SET I.art_id = (SELECT ART_ID FROM tof_articles WHERE I.art_nr = ART_ARTICLE_NR AND I.sup_id = ART_SUP_ID) WHERE I.sup_id > 0";
```

No matter if in that .csv files is one single entry or a few tens or hundreds or thousands, I always get the same error as mentioned at the beginning.

There was one issue though. For some stupid reason the /tmp partition on my CentOS server got full and some mysql tables crashed. I have used mysqlcheck with --repair option to fix them and also myisamchk. I have restarted mysql service and I see no errors with those tables.

Any help is really appreaciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear: your `SELECT ART_ID FROM tof_articles WHERE I.art_nr = ART_ARTICLE_NR AND I.sup_id = ART_SUP_ID` query returns more than one result for at least one of your CSV row.

I suggest echo-ing the CSV row BEFORE your do the query, when the error will happen, you will know wich line is causing an issue. When you get it, check your database.

Comment: I know that the error is pretty clear. The thing is that the same file was working just fine 2 days ago. Out of nowhere, yesterday I got that error. I have checked the database and that table and everything looks just fine. I have only 1 single row in my .csv file and the error is still the same. Could it be that the same entry somehow to be in the database twice?

Comment: Since you have only one line, run the SELECT ART_ID FROM tof_articles WHERE I.art_nr = ART_ARTICLE_NR AND I.sup_id = ART_SUP_ID query by itself (replace the values where needed of course), if you have a duplicated row, it will be returned by the database.

Comment: It seems that the error appears when I run this simple update sql statement:
`UPDATE preturi_import I SET I.art_id = ( SELECT ART_ID FROM tof_articles WHERE I.art_nr = ART_ARTICLE_NR AND I.sup_id = ART_SUP_ID ) WHERE I.sup_id > 0`

It has nothing to do with the import from the .csv file! Thanks for the hints!

Comment: If this helped you please mark my answer so this can be marked as solved!